# Firefox 3.6 not displaying content - xajax, jquery, css

Tags: containers, firefox3.6, xajax

I know this question may sound vague, but I have been debugging (PHP and js) our application for a day now and have not found any issues in the data generation.

Our application uses xajax to generate lists based on data that we have in our DB. we have a list in particular that works on every other browser: IE 7&8, Firefox 3.0.13(Linux) and 3.5.7 (Win, Mac), Opera (Win), Chrome 4.0.249.30(Linux) and 4.0.249.78 (Win), Safari (Win and Mac). But  firefox 3.6 in windows 7 and Mac OS 10.6.2 does not generate this list at all.

When I use firebug the div that contains the list is completely empty

```
<pre>< div id="listOutput">< /div></pre>
```

", when in it should contain all the data for the l
ist!

I have no idea why this problem could be happening, and any leads in why this may be happening would be of real help

Thank you

```
<div id = "listOutput" >
  <table class="list" >
    <tbody >
      <tr class="head" >
        <th class="noSort checkbox"><input id="selectAllRows" name="selectAllRows" title="Select all" type="checkbox" >< /th >
        <th class="ID" onclick="xajax_displayPagination(0, 20, 'id', 'ASC', xajax.getFormValues('pageForm')); xajax_displaySearch(0, 20, 'id', 'ASC', xajax.getFormValues('pageForm')); xajax_displayList(0, 20, 'id', 'ASC', xajax.getFormValues('pageForm'));"><span id="DESC">ID</span></th>
        <th class="noSort option">option< /th >
      </tr >
    </tbody >
  </table >
</div >
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what the markup looks like in the other Firefox?

Comment: Good point: Maybe that DIV should be blank (is it when you look at it in other browsers?) - it might be that the javascript dynamically 'fills' it in - rather than the data arriving fully-formed within the DIV. You getting any javascript errors on 3.6 Firefox?

Comment: Sorry I haven't had to get back to this until now. now the code is showing.

Answer (score 0):

can be related with this change in new js support for FF3.6?

"The prototype property of function instances is no longer enumerable." https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_3.6_for_developers

Answer (score 0):

Does xajax use getBoxObjectFor(), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_3.6_for_developers? If it does that could be your problem. I had to fix this because as soon as FF 3.6 came out. Our Infragistics grids did not work in certain scenarios and that was the culprit.

Here's what I did to fix it.

Note that my fix is a la jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    if ($.browser.mozilla && !document.getBoxObjectFor) {
        document.getBoxObjectFor = function(elem) {
            var boundingRect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
            var doc = elem.ownerDocument;

            // top and bottom are not rounded off in Gecko1.9
            // http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#elementviewm
            var elemTop = Math.round(boundingRect.top);
            var elemLeft = boundingRect.left;
            var docElement = doc.documentElement;

            // clientLeft and clientTop would be 0 for Gecko1.9
            // https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=174397#c34
            elemLeft += docElement.scrollLeft;
            elemTop += docElement.scrollTop;

            return { x: elemLeft, y: elemTop, width: docElement.width, height: docElement.height };
        };
    } 
});
```